# Does the location relate to subject or object?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Die Künstlerin malt eine Kirche in Russland.

I saw this sentence and wonder whether the artist is in Russia or the church is in Russia. Otherwise, might it mean either one depending on the context?

Comment: "Otherwise, might it mean either one depending on the context?" Yes, which is why a native speaker would say this differently if the sentence was supposed to stand without context.

Comment: E.g., switching the word order would be one option: "Die Künstlerin malt in Russland eine Kirche." wouldn't be ambiguous.

Answer (score 5):

It is not entirely clear what it refers to due to the very liberal placement rules in German.

Yet here the placement of the location qualifier allows to differ and indicate what it refers to: it stands next to "eine Kirche", so that is what it usually refers to. If the artist was in Russia, the adverbial should follow the verb directly:

> Die Künstlerin (malt in Russland) eine Kirche

> Die Künstlerin malt (eine Kirche in Russland)

If you really want to make it unambiguous you will want to use a subordinate sentence:

> Die Künstlerin malt, während sie in Russland ist, eine Kirche

> Die Künstlerin malt eine Kirche, die in Russland steht.

Comment: First subordinate clause in planetmakers answer is a parenthesis, and the second is a relative clause.

Comment: *the sentence should* → *the adverbial should*